How to populate Address data using Quick Action (lwc)
I'm trying to populate a 'lightning-combobox' element with an Account's address data. This component is being triggered from a "Create Case" quick action within an Account record. I'm lost and don't know how to make this work. Can anyone help?
<template>
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case" record-type-id={selectedRecordType} onsuccess={handleSuccess} onload={handleFormLoad}>
    
    <lightning-record-picker
        label="Accounts"
        placeholder="Search Accounts..."
        object-api-name="Account"
        onselection={handleAccountSelection}>
    </lightning-record-picker>

    <lightning-record-picker
        label="Contacts"
        placeholder="Search Contacts..."
        object-api-name="Contact"
        onselection={handleContactSelection}>
    </lightning-record-picker>

    <lightning-combobox
        name="Installation Address"
        label={addressOptions}
        placeholder="Address"
        options={addressOptions}
        value={value}
        onblur={handleAddressChange}>
    </lightning-combobox>

    <lightning-input
        label="Description"
        placeholder="Description"
        value={description}
        onchange={handleDescriptionChange}>
    </lightning-input>

    <lightning-button
        variant="brand"
        type="submit"
        name="save"
        label="Create Case"
        onclick={handleSubmit}>
    </lightning-button>

</lightning-record-edit-form>

import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import findById from '@salesforce/apex/AddressController.findById';

export default class AntennaInstallationComponent extends LightningElement {
@track description;
@track selectedAccountId;
@track selectedContactId;
@track account;
@track address__c;
@api addressOptions;
@api selectedAddress;
@track loading = false;

connectedCallback() {
    if (this._recordId) {
        this.findById(this._recordId);
    }
}

@api
get recordId() {
    return this._recordId;
}

set recordId(value) {
    this._recordId = value;
    if (value) {
        this.findById(value);
    }
}

findById(accID) {
    console.log('start call findById');
    this.loading = true;
    findById({ id: accID })
        .then(result => {
            console.log('findById - processing result');
            this.address__c = result;
            this.populateAddressOptions(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error on searching address:', error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            this.loading = false;
        });
    console.log('end call findById');
}

handleAccountSelection(event) {
    this.selectedAccountId = event.detail.selectedRecordId;
}

handleContactSelection(event) {
    this.selectedContactId = event.detail.selectedRecordId;
}

handleDescriptionChange(event) {
    this.description = event.detail.value;
}

handleAddressChange(event) {
    this.selectedAddress = event.detail.value;
}

populateAddressOptions(result) {
    this.addressOptions = result.map(address => {
        return {
            label: `${address.Address__Street__s} - ${address.Address__PostalCode__s}`,
            value: address.Id
        };
    });
}

}
AddressController: 
public Address__c findById(String idAcc){
    return [
    SELECT Id, Account__r.Name, 
    Account__r.Type, 
    Address__City__s, 
    Address__Street__s, 
    Address__PostalCode__s 
    FROM Address__c 
    WHERE Account__c = :idAcc];
}

Error message:
    Error on searching address: 
Object
body
: 
exceptionType
: 
"System.QueryException"
isUserDefinedException
: 
false
message
: 
"List has no rows for assignment to SObject"
stackTrace
: 
"Class.AddressRepository.findById: line 3, column 1\nClass.AddressController.findById: line 10, column 1"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
errorType
: 
"fetchResponse"
headers
: 
{}
ok
: 
false
status
: 
500
statusText
: 
"Server Error"


You're trying to assig a query to a single value. Apex permits this if, and only if, there is exactly one match.
// Assume there is a record available
Account record = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];

While getting zero or more than one value results in an exception:
Account record = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 0]; // No rows for assignment...

// Assume two records:
Account record = [SELECT Id FROM Account]; // Too many rows for assignment

The solution is to return a list:
public Address__c[] findById(String idAcc){
    return [
    SELECT Id, Account__r.Name, 
    Account__r.Type, 
    Address__City__s, 
    Address__Street__s, 
    Address__PostalCode__s 
    FROM Address__c 
    WHERE Account__c = :idAcc];
}

This will ensure that you don't receive an exception on account of not having any data.
Also, note that you did not define _record in the class, which will also cause problems.
_recordId;
@api get recordId {
  return this._recordId;
}
set recordId(value) {
  this._recordId = value;
}

Finally, you should consider using private fields for variables like _record. To do this, prefix the variable with # instead.
#recordId;
@api get recordId {
  return this.#recordId;
}
set recordId(value) {
  this.#recordId = value;
}

